# Filereader.read() method not working

Tags: java, filereader, file-read

I have written the following code that creates a file, adds text to it and then reads the file. My problem is that on execution, the contents of the file are not displayed on the screen, though the contents are added in the text file.

Following is my code

```
import java.io.*;
class prc4{
public static void main(String args[]){
try{
    File f = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_25\\bin\\file1.txt");
    if (f.createNewFile()){
        System.out.println("File is created!");
        }else{
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
        }
    FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter("file1.txt");
    f1.write("Hello World. This is a sample text file!");
    FileReader f2 = new FileReader("file1.txt");
    int x = f2.read();
    while(x != -1){
        System.out.println((char)x);
        x = f2.read();
    }
    f1.close();
    f2.close();
}catch(Exception e){    }
}
}
```

Output:
[image]

[image]

In the text file:

[image]

Comment: Try to close the `Writer` before you attempt to read from this file . Also, don't ignore Exceptions you may have in your `catch` block .

Comment: Program output and file contents are text. Do not post text as screenshots. Post text as text inside your question.

Comment: @Berger thanks a ton! It worked. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close, or at least [flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#flush--), the writer before you read from the file.  Writing to files is buffered, and so the contents are not actually in the file yet when you are reading from it.  I recommend closing the writer using a try-with-resources construct:

```
try (FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter("file1.txt"))
    {
    f1.write("Hello World. This is a sample text file!");
    }

try (FileReader f2 = new FileReader("file1.txt");)
    {
    int x = f2.read();
    while(x != -1){
        System.out.println((char)x);
        x = f2.read();
    }
    }
```

Note, too, that you are calling `println()` for each character, which means that each character will be printed on a separate line.  This may be what you want, or you may want to call `print()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Flush and close your `writer` and you can also use a `BufferedReader` to read the file content line by line to print its content.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        File f = new File("file1.txt");
        if (f.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("File is created!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
        }
        FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter(f);
        f1.write("Hello World. This is a sample text file!");
        f1.flush();
        f1.close();  

        FileReader f2 = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(f2);
            String l = reader.readLine();

            while (l!=null) {
                System.out.println(l);
                l = reader.readLine();
            }

        }finally {
            try { 
                if (reader!=null) 
                  reader.close(); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have written your file (`f1.write()`):

```
    f1.close();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file1.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try { if (reader!=null) reader.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a BufferedReader which is a generic reader for character-input stream. Is best option to read from text files

```
class prc4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            File f = new File(".\\file1.txt");
            if (f.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File is created!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
            }
            FileWriter f1 = new FileWriter(".\\file1.txt");
            f1.write("Hello World. This is a sample text file!");
            FileReader f2 = new FileReader(".\\file1.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f2); 
            String s; 
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                System.out.println(s); 
            } 
            br.close();
            f1.close();
            f2.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```